# Logging HLS chunk requests

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I want to monitor the switching between differnt bitrates on a HLS stream in Android. So i was thinking to monitor the HLS chunk requests. and parse these. Do you guys have any idea how i would go around and do this?

I have already tried monitoring the on videosizechanged but i do not think this will suffice...

```
        vv.setVideoPath("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8");
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mMediaPlayer = mp;
                mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "perhaps changed bitrate?");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        vv.start();
```

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do with android.media.MediaPlayer API. In the callback onVideoSizeChanged() there is no news about it. You can be lucky checking the callback [android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener.html)  with the event [MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) and his extra, but the behaviour changes according to the manufacturer.

My suggestion is to switch to the new [ExoPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), an open source project powered by Google. In the last release, it handles [HLS](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/hls). Through the class [HlsChunkSource](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/hls/HlsChunkSource.java), you can retrieve information about all chunk request ( for instance by the method getChunkOperation() ).